# Typescript Transformer - QuestionToken missing

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I made a simple transformer.

```
import ts from "typescript";
import path from "path";

export function Transformer(
    checker: ts.TypeChecker,
): ts.TransformerFactory<ts.SourceFile> {
    return (context) => {
        const v: ts.Visitor = (node: ts.Node) => {
            console.log(node.kind);
            return ts.visitEachChild(node, v, context);
        };
        return (node) => ts.visitNode(node, v);
    };
}

async function MainAsync() {
    const dir = path.resolve("./");
    const filePathIn = path.resolve(dir, "./src/test.ts");
    console.log({ filePathIn });
    const program = ts.createProgram([filePathIn], {});
    const checker = program.getTypeChecker();
    const source = program.getSourceFile(filePathIn);
    console.log("checking source");
    if (!source) return;
    console.log("run through transformer");
    await ts.transform(source, [Transformer(checker)]);
    // console.log({ result });
}

MainAsync();
```

Testing against a simple `test.ts` file

```
export class TestMe {
    id0?: {
        test0: string;
    };
    id: number;
}
```

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-transformer-qdtp2?file=/src/index.ts:0-1207)

The console output is

```
297 - SourceFile
252 - ClassDeclaration
92 - ExportKeyword
78 - Identifier
163 - PropertyDeclaration
78 - Identifier
>>> MISSING 57 - QuestionToken
177 - TypeLiteral
162 - PropertySignature
78 - Identifier
147 - StringKeyword
163 - PropertyDeclaration
78 - Identifier
144 - NumberKeyword
```

Note that its missing `57 - QuestionToken`. I also confirmed the expected test.ts output via [TypeScript AST Viewer](https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4BVhpgWWDgG8AoASAEsATABgH4AuEi8mXGW5vKSgOwDmAbgoBfEVWrM+AVwC2AI2BQRo0kA).

Typescript still checks if its an optional type if I try to use it via VSCode. Whats going on? How do I force the `QuestionToken` to appear?

[Github reference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42328)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a `tokenVisitor` to `visitEachChild`:

```
import ts = require("typescript");
import path = require("path");

export function Transformer(
    checker: ts.TypeChecker,
): ts.TransformerFactory<ts.SourceFile> {
    return (context) => {
        const v: ts.Visitor = (node: ts.Node) => {
            console.log(node.kind + ' - ' + ts.SyntaxKind[node.kind]);
            return ts.visitEachChild(node, v, context, undefined, visitToken);
        };
        return (node) => ts.visitNode(node, v);
    };

    function visitToken(t: ts.Node) {
        console.log(ts.SyntaxKind[t.kind]);
        return t;
    }
}

async function MainAsync() {
    const dir = path.resolve("./");
    const filePathIn = path.resolve(dir, "test.ts");
    console.log({ filePathIn });
    const program = ts.createProgram([filePathIn], {});
    const checker = program.getTypeChecker();
    const source = program.getSourceFile(filePathIn);
    console.log("checking source");
    if (!source) return;
    console.log("run through transformer");
    await ts.transform(source, [Transformer(checker)]);
}

MainAsync().then(() => { });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Where do you find this documented? I've been working off typescripts Compiler API docs and various online samples and I hadn't come across this.